# Graphs with a pair vertices satisfies a neighbourhood condition (Reference request)

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

Let $G$ be a finite simple graph. Let $u$ and $v$ be two district vertices of $G$ such that $N_G(u)\backslash\{v\} = N_G(v)\backslash\{u\}$ where $N_G(u)$ denotes the set of vertices of $G$ adjacent to the vertex $u$. I have the following questions.

a) is there any name for the pair $\{u,v\}$ satisfying the above neighbourhood condition?

b) is there any name for the graph $G$ in which there is a pair $\{u,v\}$ satisfying the above neighbourhood condition? If so kindly share some references.

Answer (score 1):

Two vertices having the same neighbourhood in a graph are often times called twins or clones.

It seems there are different definitions taking into account the adjacency of $(u,v)$. Your definition refers to twins/clones in general but even if $(u,v)$ is an edge they might be called "true twins" : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance-hereditary_graph#/media/File:Distance-hereditary_construction.svg and if they are not they will be clones.

From what I've come across there isn't any particular name for a graph that admits a pair of twins, but here's a nice reference on their use in a pretty neat and short result : https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0095895606000062.

Comment: Thanks. I think here we are not talking about twins because we don't want their neighbourhoods to be equal. We want neighbourhood minus particular point of two vertices are equal.

Comment: Well the particular points we are removing are exactly the other vertex, so it's like you are allowing "adjacent twins" on top of "non-adjacent" twins. The clones in the article I referenced are not suited to your definition though since they imply $u,v$ are not adjacent. What context does your question arise from if I may ask ?

Comment: I am trying to calculate the automorphosm group of join of two graphs. It there are vertices satisfying the given conditions then they are creating problem for me. So I want to read more about such vertices.